# Using CSS to make div holding OBJECT HTML file the same height

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve the following (without JS) with CSS, but with no luck :-(

I have a div holding an object which loads a php file. Now what I need is some CSS which can make the DIV holding the page/object be the same heigh as the page/object loaded.

```
<div style="margin: 0 auto; width:100%; height:auto;display:block; overflow:hidden;" id="news">

<object id="newsDataHolder" data="showinfo.php" style="width:100%; height:100%; clear: both;margin:0px; padding:0px;" type="text/html">
</object>

</div>
```

If I can force the holding DIV to be the same height as the page loaded in the HTML OBJECT it would be great. However, setting fixed heights on the holding DIV will generate too much space OR enable the scrolling of the holding DIV.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Yes. In my code is is set to auto. The holding div. Not the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that you should set your `object` to `display: block`. The rest of your CSS probably isn't necessary. It's hard to say more without a demo of your issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/h8kucwpj/

```
.container object {
    display: block;
}
```